# Lenovo Y50-70 Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon NVIDIA Geforce GTX 860M driver problem

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, cinnamon, graphics, display

I have been trying in vain to get the discrete video card to work. I have tried applying all of the nvidia drivers listed in Driver Manager here:
[image]
But after a reboot, all I'll get is a black screen with a cursor, which requires me to reconfigure my Xorg. After doing a `startx` at the end of this reconfiguration step, the desktop graphic interface will come back with a message that Cinnamon has crashed and is currently in fallback mode. I can only then revert things back to their normal states by enabling the nouveau driver :(. I have also updated my kernel to 4.8.0-32-generic, but again nothing changed.

How can I get the discrete video card to work?

Edit: After deleting some PPA with the Software Sources GUI, my Driver Manager looks like this
[image: Driver Manager after PPA deleted]

Comment: First of all remove your ppa I assume it's https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+ppa-packages?start=75&batch=75 with ppa-purge.

Comment: I removed my ppa from Software Sources and reran Driver Manager. Now nvidia-367 shows up as "recommended". Selecting it still causes Cinnamon to crash as before. :(

Comment: Did you remove the ppa with ppa-purge? If not that is a problem, because the packages from there stay's in your system.

Comment: I know this is a dumb question but how do I find which ppa to remove with ppa-purge?

Comment: Please see photo of updated Driver Mananger in the edited question.

Comment: `sudo apt install ppa-purge` Add the ppa again. `sudo apt update` Then `sudo ppa-purge ppa:repository-name/subdirectory`   Then the ppa package will be downgraded to the versions from offiziel sources.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to ask how do I know what to put in for "repository-name/subdirectory"?

Answer (score 0):

First add the ppa again, or it will not work. I think it was [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau) If yes, easier command

```
sudo ppa-purge -o xorg-edgers

sudo apt update && sudo apt install nvidia-361
```

Don't be confused, this is the Meta-package for nvidia-367

According to [nvidia-page](http://www.nvidia.de/Download/driverResults.aspx/105370/de) supports the driver your card and it is no beta.

Comment: So I ran `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`, then `sudo apt-get update` before using ppa-purge to remove them. Then doing `sudo apt update && sudo apt install nvidia-361` followed by a reboot again resulted in a black screen with a non-blinking cursor with the only difference being that the Mint start-up sound could now be heard. Doing `sudo Xorg - configure` and `sudo cp xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf` again causes Cinnamon to crash. Switching back to nouveau lands me in software-rendering mode... :| How do I get out of this?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core` seems to have helped me get rid of the "software-rendering" mode message. :|

Comment: Still haven't been able to get this card to be recognized by Mint... Sad :(